# Automating org-mode export with org-reveal exporter

Tags: org-mode

I have an org-mode document that I am exporting to reveal.js via [org-reveal](https://github.com/yjwen/org-reveal).
Currently, I do a `(require 'ox-reveal)`  and then I can do `C-e R R` from within my org-mode document.
I am wondering how I can script this so I can do this from within bash.
I currently have a bash script for a related project that does uses batch mode as follows,

`emacs my-doc.org --batch -f org-html-export-to-html --kill`

I am wondering how to adapt this to org-reveal.
Part of the problem is making sure `(require 'ox-reveal)` happens in batch mode.

Looking forward to any pointers here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With external config file,

```
emacs --batch --no-init-file --load config.el --find-file to-export.org --funcall org-export-function
```

Or without your "normal" `init.el`,

```
emacs --batch --eval "(require 'ox-backend)" --find-file to-export.org --funcall org-export-function
```

Comment: Thank you rasmus. I really appreciate your answer. One final point of confusion, for the org-reveal exporter, I currently use 'C-c e R R` to call the exporter. There must be a function I can call that does the export directly, but I am not sure what it is. Do you happen to know?

Comment: I think it is org-reveal-export-to-html, as seen in the bottom of https://github.com/yjwen/org-reveal/blob/master/ox-reveal.el